# Printing TODO: comments from a text file in Python

Tags: python, text, todo

In my Project I want to extract the to do list from a text file. Here is my progress so far.

This is the content of `todolist.txt` text file

```
#TODO:example4
def printName():
    name=input("Enter your name: ")
    print("Hello " + name)
 TODO:example3
def printNumbers():
    for i in range (0,10):#TODO:example2
        print(i)


printName()
printNumbers()
#TODO: example1
```

and here is my Python code for extracting lines with **TODO**:

```
file=open("todolist.txt","r")

word="TODO:"

for line in file:
    if word in line:
        print(line)
```

And when I run this program the result is:

```
#TODO:example4

 TODO:example3

    for i in range (0,10):#TODO:example2

#TODO: example1


Process finished with exit code 0
```

So my problem is here I want to extract and print TODO lines *only* but as you can see from above, for **#TODO:example2** my program printed the previous code on that spesific line too.

What I want to do is basicly just printing TODO comments.

Comment: find the index of the # character and print the line from that point.
with `line[index:]` where index point to the # character. You can find it with the find method for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the line by `'TODO'` then get the last item.

```
word="TODO:"
with open("todolist.txt") as file:    
    for line in file:
        if word in line:
            print("#TODO:" + line.split(word)[-1])
```

Comment: Thank you this one helped. I am a beginner in Python. Can you expain the `line.split(Word)[-1]` part ? What does the -1 value do?

Comment: @onurcevik [-1] usage, gets the last item on objects that can be indexed. Like [0] is the first item, [1] is the second item etc. Since split returns a list, it gets the last item, in this case, it is the part after "TODO".

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex:

```
import re

with open("todolist.txt") as f:
    file_content = f.read()

print(re.findall(r'^\s*#TODO:.+$', file_content, re.MULTILINE))

# ['#TODO:example4', '#TODO: example1']
```

`'^\s*#TODO:.+$'` will match every line that:

- starts with any number of spaces (0 or more)
- contains #TODO followed by anything (1 or more)
- contains nothing else